# Completeness property and computability

Tags: real-analysis, computability

I have this axiom which states the completeness property of a set $A$:

> Suppose that $A$ is a set. Every non-empty bounded above subset of $A$ has a least upper bound.

But then my prof told me that this Completeness axiom causes computability issues (later on he talked about computable numbers -- so I have been thinking that he actually referred to that). The thing is, I don't really get what he means by that. What's the connection between that statement above with computability? Hope one of you can help? Cheers!

Comment: I don't know what your professor is talking about either. What was the context?

Comment: @StefanMesken: Hmm we talked about computable numbers at the end, so I have been thinking that he actually referred to that part. But still, I have no idea how to make the connection.

Comment: Probably the comment was simply that a supremum of computable numbers needs not be computable.

Comment: Maybe he just meant that the completeness axiom for reals implies that there are uncomputable reals (working in some second order arithmetic base theory).

Comment: @Jonathan: Hmm can you explain it a bit more mate? Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main link is related to failures of the completeness theorem if we read "real" as "computable real".

A [Specker sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specker_sequence) is a bounded, increasing, computable sequence of rationals whose limit is not computable. If we view the sequence as a set of rationals, it is a decidable, bounded, nonempty set of rationals whose supremum is not computable.